# TextView OnClickListener Property not working

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am trying to call another layout when clicking a TextView on my MainActivity layout. I tried using the onClick() on the XML file but, due to the course purposes, it requires that everything is handled from the Java file. Following is the sample code given by the instructor that, in theory, should work, but it doesn't, followed by my very own code. When I click on the TextView to call on the other layout the program crashes.

My MainAcitivity.java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView numbers = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numbers);
    TextView family = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.family);
    TextView colors = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.colors);
    TextView phrases = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.phrases);

    numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Here is my xml file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numbers"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:background="@color/category_numbers"
    android:text="@string/category_numbers" />
```

The file crashes with an error

```
    Process: com.example.android.miwok, PID: 28613
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.miwok/com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3782)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8086)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8074)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3755)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3961) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2386) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
```

Comment: Write `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` just after calling `super` then define textviews.

Answer (score 0):

Move the setContentView() after super, follow bellow code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    TextView numbers = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numbers);
    TextView family = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.family);
    TextView colors = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.colors);
    TextView phrases = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.phrases);

    numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```